# conditional declaration of type using decltype

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, decltype

I thought that conditional type could be declared using `decltype` in template functions. But it seems not. Could anyone point out what's wrong with my test code?

```
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>
using boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr;

#define print_type(var) do { \
  std::cout << type_id_with_cvr<decltype(var)>().pretty_name() << std::endl; \
} while(0)

template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto max(T1 a, T2 b) -> decltype(a < b ? b : a) {
  decltype(a < b ? b : a) c = a < b ? b : a;
  print_type(c);
  return a < b ? b : a;
}

int main() {
  int i = 10;
  double d = 3.3;

  decltype(i < d? d : i) r = i < d? d : i;
  print_type(r); // -> double
  std::cout << r << std::endl; // 10
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that your intention with

```
decltype( a < b ? a : b )
```

was to obtain the type of `b` when `a < b` and the type of `a` otherwise.

That is: I suppose that your intention was to obtain a type determined **run time** according to the runt time values of `a` and `b`.

This is impossible in C++ because the type of a variable must be decided **compile time**.

With that `decltype()` you obtain the type of the ternary operator

```
a < b ? a : b
```

that doesn't depend from the values of `a` and `b` but only from their types.

So, in the case

```
decltype(i < d? d : i)
```

where `i` is an `int` and `d` is a `double`, you obtain a `double` and the values of `i` and `d` are irrelevant.

Comment: For what ground c++(decltype) decide to use `double` rather than `int`?

Comment: @DanielLee - For it being the **common type** between `double` and `int`.

Comment: @DanielLee, `double` is the common type of `int` and `double`. Mainly because converting `int` to `double` commonly either preserves the value or approximates it reasonably. In fact, it's common for conversions from a 32-bit `int` to a `double` to be non-narrowing, as IEEE-754 doubles can store up to ±2⁵³ without loss of precision. On the flip side, converting from `double` to `int` misses out on many, many values. C++ simply requires the conditional expression to resolve to a compile-time-known type, so it chooses the one that doesn't miss out on tons of values from the other.

Comment: `std::conditional` exists.... Yes, it must be decided at compile-time, but there's template magic to let you do stuff.

Comment: @StoryTeller @chris @AlexanderHuszagh Thanks. But all I know about `common type` of c++ is this. std::common_type: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type not a common type. Should I take it as a natural behavior of c++ like a magic?

Comment: @DanielLee - There's no magic. C++ is a standardized language. You may read [how the common type is deduced](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.cond) yourself. And FYI, you can only tag *one* person in a comment. You tagged me first, so only I was notified.